# How to prune hydrangeas that are too heavy

Tags: pruning, hydrangea

I recently purchased a half dozen hydrangeas from a local garden store and they've started blooming. However they are quite droopy, with the droopiest pictured here. They seem healthy otherwise: plenty of water, the get New Jersey summer sun from sunrise to early afternoon, and were planted with a scoop of organic Holly tone.

My assumption is the blooms are sitting on the ground because they're too heavy for the young stem to support. Is that a likely explanation? If so what's the proper way to prune them?

They are Nikko Blues. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

They look like a cultivar of *Hydrangea arborescens* (I would've said 'Annabelle' except some of the flowers are blue). Falling down because the blooms are too heavy is exactly what cultivars of H. arborescens do. In my experience, you cannot prune them in any way that allows for the plants to stay upright. Your best hope is to grow the hydrangeas througt peony supports. This will allow the top-heavy stems to rest on the supports and not on the ground.